# Hard problem from elementary geometry - how do I discard this option for x?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I came across this problem in a FB group.
Seems like a math competition problem.

See the drawing below.

[image: pic1]

First we draw the big quarter circle,
then the blue semi-circle, then the blue full circle.

Finally we draw the small yellow circle.

In this order we do the drawing.

We need to prove $r/R = 3/29$.

OK, I denote $x=r/R$.

The easy part is to compute the radius of the blue full circle. It turns out to be $3R/8$. Then it took me a lot of time and pain (about 8 hours in total maybe) but I was finally able to come up with an equation for $x=r/R$.

Here it is

[WA Equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%285%2F4%29%20*%20%283%20*%20%285-4*x%29%20%2F%20%2825*%20%281%2B4*x%29%29%20-%20%2820*x-3%29%20%2F%20%2812*x%2B3%29%29%29%20%20%5E%202%20%20%2B%20%20%28%20%285-4*x%29%20%2F%20%285%20*%20%281%2B4*x%29%29%20%29%20%5E%202%20%3D%201%20)

I can explain how I got this equation (I use twice the cosine rule, other things, etc. etc.), but this is not really my issue.

Now I have one final issue to overcome. The algebraic equation has 2 roots for x.

So how do I prove $x$ cannot be $3/5$?

From the drawing it's kind of obvious $r/R$ cannot be $3/5$ but how do I discard this option in a more rigorous way? I know that "kind of obvious" doesn't count in maths.

Comment: $r \lt MB = R/2$.

Comment: It's worth noting that $x=3/5$ corresponds to the "other" circle internally tangent to $\bigcirc O$ and externally tangent to the blue circles; the algebra can't distinguish the cases, so it gives the two roots. @Sam's comment is the key to making the intended choice; expressed another way, you need $2r<R$: the diameter of the target circle must be smaller than the radius of $\bigcirc O$ to fit inside the quadrant. (Incidentally, the center of the "other" circle lies on line $OA$. I wonder if there's a way to make this fact "obvious", and then also to leverage it to find the target circle.)

Comment: @Sam Why? Yes it looks so but why is it so?

Comment: @peter.petrov Because the area of the yellow circle is less than the area of the big quarter circle.

Comment: @Sam Ah, of course. Thanks. Sometimes I don't see the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the area of the yellow circle is less than the area of the big quarter circle we have

$$\pi r^2 \lt \frac{1}{4} \pi R^2 $$ i.e.

$$r / R < \frac{1}{2}$$

So $x = r/R$ cannot be $3/5$

$\Rightarrow x = r/R = 3/29$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hint: As you see in figure there is second circle (5) tangent to circles 1, 2 and 3. In figure:

$R_1=100$

$R_2=\frac {R_1}4=25$

$R_3=\frac{3R_1}8 =37.5$

$R_4=\frac{3R_1}{29}$

$R_5=\frac {3R_1}5=60$

To find the equation you may use Descartes Theorem:

$$\big(\frac1{R_1}+\frac 1{R_2}+\frac 1{R_3}+\frac 1 r\big)^2=2\big(\frac1{R_1^2}+\frac 1{R_2^2}+\frac 1{R_3^2}+\frac 1 {r^2}\big)$$